# Power conversion causing huge increase in amperage

Tags: inverter, amperage, hid, dc-ac

I've got a transformer ballast driving an HID lamp. When the transformer is wired to 110VAC, it's using about 700mA. When I drive it with a 12v battery and power inverter (to 110VAC) the transformer buzzez much more loudly, pulls around 5 amps from the inverter, and I read over 8 amps between the inverter and the battery.

Why the 800% increase in amp draw just from using a 12v battery as my source? Is there a way I can do this more efficiently?

Comment: Chances are that your inverter is square wave or modified sine wave inverter, but we need more details to be sure. It would help if you include diagrams, schematics, photos of your setup, anything to give us details other than the increased current when using inverter.

Comment: 8A between the inverter and the battery is pretty good (96W) compared with 77W from 110VAC. The "5A" between inverter and ballast must be reactive power? As the other comment suggests, poor waveform won't help and a puer sinewave inverter would be better. But it'll still take nearly 8A (maybe 7A) from the battery.

Comment: For an ideal 100% efficient inverter, Power In == Power Out.Since your Power out is 77W (110 x 0.7) then you can calculate expected current in with a 12V supply -> 77 / 12 == 6.42A. So if you're actually measuring 8A with your less than ideal inverter, then it's about 80% efficient - seems pretty reasonable for a cheap & nasty inverter ... If you were really pulling 5A from the inverter then the smoke would be coming out somewhere, so I'm passing that off as a measurement error.